# How to access keyword of keyword?

Tags: python, matplotlib, keyword

I am trying to access keyword of keyword -specifically, I have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
plot1 = fig.add_subplot(211, ylabel = 'foo',xlabel='bar')
```

and I want to change to font size of the ylabel to 10 and font size of xlabel to 20. ylabel and xlabel both have their own keywords (i.e. https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylabel.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylabel) but I am not sure how I can control their keywords in the same line that I called add_subplot.

Of course, I can do this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
plot1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
fig.set_ylabel(ylabel = 'foo', fontsize = 10) 
fig.set_xlabel(xlabel = 'bar', fontsize = 20)
```

But this way requires more lines of code than I'd like.

I've tried calling ylabel.fontsize but that didn't work:

fig.add_subplot(211, ylabel.fontsize = 50)

Which just gives SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Comment: In function args, a keyword is just that, a keyword. It doesn't have attributes. Just search in add_subplot whether there's a keyword arg to change ylabel font size. Also, this `But this way requires more lines of code than I'd like.` is more often than not, a completely pointless preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But this way requires more lines of code than I'd like.

For a 2D plot, they are literally just 2 (short) lines of code. I would strongly advise against "saving" lines of code, especially in a language like Python where the PEP standard for line length is 80 characters, i.e. many short lines are better than few long lines.

For the problem at hand If you really want to  to save (maximum) 1 line of code you could try updating the rcParams dictionary.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams.update({'xtick.labelsize':'x-large', 'ytick.labelsize':'x-large'})
fig = plt.figure()
plot1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
```

Careful though, this dictionary update is overriding the default label sizes for this script, not just for the figure at hand.